# Grid-like behavior using CSS Flexbox for dynamic components

Tags: css, flexbox

I am using React and I can add new items using my form.

```
                <div className="wrapper">
                    {
                        this.props.routers.map((item, idx) => {
                            return (
                                <Tag
                                    className='tag'
                                    key={idx}
                                    onRemove={() => this.deleteElem(idx)}>
                                        {`${username}@${addr}`}
                                </Tag>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </div>
```

This is part of my dynamic component and it renders new tags as I new more items.

My style looks like:

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
}

.tag {
    margin: 1em 0.5em;
    background: #017cad;
}
```

with a few number of items,

[image]

it works fine, but when I add more and more items,

[image]

Using Flexbox, how can I set the items not to exceed the wrapper and go to the next line when it's already full in one row?

Comment: `flex-wrap:wrap`

Comment: flex-wrap where? I tried for both but didn't work

Comment: on the flex container, the `wrapper`